# Can't find Inkscape in Dash

Tags: 12.04

According to the Ubuntu Software Center, Inkscape is installed but it doesn't show up when searching for it in Dash.
I can't open it by associating an svg-file with it since it can't find it.
I've tried to un-install and reinstall it with no luck.
What is wrong?

Best regards
Anders

Comment: Can you open it by running `inkscape -g path/to/png/or/svg` in terminal?

Comment: No, it says that:

Comment: The program 'inkscape' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install inkscape.

Comment: The problem is that according to Software Center it IS installed.

Comment: try `find /usr/share/applications -name inkscape` and `find /usr -name inkscape`

Comment: So install it via terminal?

Comment: sudo apt-get install inkscape
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get install inkscape
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
inkscape is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
sudo dpkg -r inkscape
```

If it is successfull or not, then run

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting Gedit delete the whole section starts with,

`Package: inkscape`

Then Save the file and close.

Then install it again

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't start the application from the Terminal because it says that it doesn't exist. Then when I try to download it with 'sudo apt-get' it says that it is already installed. No icon can be found in the /usr/share/applications/ folder.

Comment: I edited the answer